# Bootstrap p-value for rate ratio

Tags: bootstrap

I used the bootstrap method to calculate the 95% CI of a rate ratio, but wonder how I could calculate a p-value to test the significance of the rate ratio by bootstrap?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, perhaps you want to consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/576189/491396).

Comment: What type of bootstrap CI did you use? Percentile? Normal? BCa?

Comment: I used Percentile